# ubuntu 18.04 lamp stack installed in root partition taking full space

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, php, lamp

I have a problem on my dedicated server.
I wrongly configured it at the beginning, today I got a php error saying that there was no space left on the device. I checked my directories and saw that /dev/md3 was full (logs and websites was filling the space completely) here's what it shows:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  912K  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/md3         20G   16G  3.0G  84% /
tmpfs           7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md4        392G   71M  372G   1% /home
/dev/md2        487M  214M  244M  47% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1  510M  6.1M  504M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/0
```

I cleared some logs and files and saved 3gb, but I would like to ask if someone can point me in the right direction, I know that I never had to install my lamp stack as root in this folder but didn't realize, I have lot of space on /dev/md4, is there any solution to move my lamp stack and websites to it ? or to resize my /dev/md3 partition ?

Thank's in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to remount the devices so that /var is mounted on /dev/md4. The easiest way to do this would be a from-scratch setup of the server.

Alternativly you could migrate the data directories for apache2 and mysql to /home.
A tutorial for mysql can be found here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a-mysql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-18-04

For apache2 you could just create a folder /home/www with user permissions for www-data and adjust the Directory directive of you apache vhost file to point to that folder.

Comment: Moving `/var` is a bad idea. This must actually be on the root filesystem in most Linux distributions (maybe all?), or they will fail to boot. Better to move `/var/lib/mysql` or the speciific directory containing all the files.

Comment: Yes right, and that's why I didn't suggest to move /var. The best thing would be to mount /var on the biggest device available, which in this case is /dev/md4. The tutorial describes how to move /var/lib/mysql to another directory.

Comment: Wait, what? You didn't suggest to move `/var`, but then six words later you say the best thing is to move it? I'm very confused.

Comment: I recommended mounting /var on the biggest device (/dev/md4). That's what I would do. **Alternativly** (e.g. if re-mounting should prove to be too tricky) Lio could move the contents of /var/lib/mysql to another directory as described in the digitalocean tutorial, but that would not be my choice. It is nevertheless possible, I did it once on a ha-cluster where /var should not be mounted on the drbd device. It worked but it isn't nice. I hope that this clears it up …

Comment: OK, so you did recommend moving `/var`. Again, that will likely result in an unbootable system.

Comment: I think I got you now: by "moving" /var you meant to move the folder on a different partition than / while I thought you meant moving the data to a different directory. So you're right.
But in my experience it is save to mount /var to a different partition than / and I did that on serveral servers.